# WMP make audio CD from mp4

Tags: windows, audio, windows-media-player, burning

If I have an MP4 video downloaded from youtube and wish to burn the audio (but not video) to a CD playable in my car, will WMP do this?

Will Windows Media Player do this automatically or do I have to set it up?

Comment: WMP can't burn audio from a video. Try (http://www.youtube-mp3.org/) to download an mp3 of the video, and then you can use WMP to burn the audio CD. There will be audio quality loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Media Player cannot strip audio from a video, and then burn it as an audio disc. There are third party tools that can do this, but a quick fix would just be to use a site like
http://www.youtube-mp3.org/ which will provide an mp3 convert of the youtube video's audio track.

Being a conversion this means there will be some quality loss, but in most cases it still sounds fine especially if the video has a good quality audio track.

Windows Media Player supports burning mp3 files to an audio cd so you can proceed from there as you would normally. Open Windows Media Player, click on the burn tab, drag in your tracks, and click burn.